# React.js Autocomplete from scratch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

As part of a technical test, I've been asked to write an autocomplete input in React. I've done this but I'd now like to add the functionality of navigating up and down the rendered list with the arrow keys. I've done some extensive Googling and found nothing React specific apart from npm packages.

To be clear, I'm looking for something like this but for React: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

All I basically need is the arrow button functionality, I've got everything else working fine.

Cheers

Here's an example that I tried but couldn't get working.

```
export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      cursor: 0,
      result: []
    }
  }

handleKeyDown(e) {
    const { cursor, result } = this.state
    // arrow up/down button should select next/previous list element
    if (e.keyCode === 38 && cursor > 0) {
      this.setState( prevState => ({
        cursor: prevState.cursor - 1
      }))
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40 && cursor < result.length - 1) {
      this.setState( prevState => ({
        cursor: prevState.cursor + 1
      }))
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { cursor } = this.state

    return (
      <Container>
        <Input onKeyDown={ this.handleKeyDown }/>
        <List>
          {
            result.map((item, i) => (
              <List.Item
                key={ item._id }
                className={cursor === i ? 'active' : null}
              >
                <span>{ item.title }</span>
              </List.Item>
            ))
          }
        </List>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is my code:

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      location: '',
      searchName: '',
      showSearch: false,
      cursor: 0
    };
  }

handleKeyPress = e => {
    const { cursor, searchName } = this.state;
    // arrow up/down button should select next/previous list element
    if (e.keyCode === 38 && cursor > 0) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        cursor: prevState.cursor - 1
      }));
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40 && cursor < searchName.length - 1) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        cursor: prevState.cursor + 1
      }));
    }
  };

 render() {
    const { searchName, location } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="Search">
        <h1>Where are you going?</h1>
        <form id="search-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="location">Pick-up Location</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="location"
            value={location}
            placeholder="city, airport, station, region, district..."
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
            onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
          />

          {this.state.showSearch ? (
            <Suggestions searchName={searchName} />
          ) : null}

          <button value="submit" type="submit" id="search-button">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Code that renders the list from the restful API:

```
.then(res =>
  this.setState({
    searchName: res.data.results.docs.map(array => (
      <a href="#">
        <div
          key={array.ufi}
          className="locations"
        >
          {array.name}
        </div>
      </a>
    ))
  })
);
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to implement the arrow functionality you want yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: I've tried a few things I found on here but it didn't work. I'll post my code now.

Comment: create function `handleKeyDown` as `handleKeyDown = (e) => ...`, or use `onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}` for the function to get the correct `this` context

Comment: Tried that but can't get it to cycle still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are defining a function as `handleKeyDown(e) {...}` the context `this` is not pointing to the context of class instance, the context will be supplied by onKeyDown (and I suppose it's `window` as `this`)

So, you have 2 ways to go:

1. declare your function as `handleKeyDown = (e) => {...}`
2. bind handleKeyDown context to component instance like `onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}`

Also, don't forget that you may want a mod items.length counter, meaning when your press down and the last item is already selected, it would go to the first item.

Your api usage with storing markdown into the state is just a terrible thing to do. You don't have access to these strings anymore, instead save it as a plain array. Pass it where you need it, and use it to create jsx there.

Also, you don't use cursor from your state at all.

Comment: Declared an event handler and the cursor counts correctly but it's not highlighting the options. I suspect it's because I've not assigned the value to the returned list.

Comment: @DanielCross I don't know the List.Item implementation, does it take className prop?

Comment: My list renders on keyPressUp and does a get request to a restful API. Here's the code for that:

I've changed the classname and tried that option but it still won't work.

Comment: @DanielCross yeah, don't do that, instead save the array as is, and convert it to the jsx where needed (it seems to be Suggestions component)

Comment: makes sense. Thanks